# Uploading images near of markdown

Tags: gatsby, netlify-cms

I have a website developed using Gatsby.js. I have integrated Netlify CMS. I would like to upload images and other files to the same folder where markdown will be placed i. e. in `{{year}}-{{month}}-{{day}}_{{slug}}/`.

Is it really to do that?

```
// admin/config.yml:

backend:
  name: github
  repo: ###

media_folder: packages/modern-agency/static/assets
public_folder: /assets

collections:
  - name: blog
    label: Blog
    folder: packages/modern-agency/content/blog
    create: true
    slug: "{{year}}-{{month}}-{{day}}_{{slug}}/index"
    fields:
      - { name: title, label: Title }
      - { name: date, label: Date, widget: datetime }
      - { name: description, label: Description }
      - { name: tags, label: Tags, widget: list }
      - { name: cover, label: Cover, widget: image }
      - { name: body, label: Body, widget: markdown }
```

Comment: AFAIK, it is not possible to do so at the moment. Uploaded images can only go into a single folder

Answer (score 0):

It seems I found the solution: [article](https://www.frontendstumbles.com/using-gatsby-image-with-netlify-cms/)